# Keeping state between pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I need help managing state between pages..
In the first page I update my map to change a value. When I print this value it works but in my other page the value is still the first value I gave.. How can I do to keep this value even in my second page?

Setting the state :
I update the value of color into a map depending on the user input

```
if (country.containsKey(guess)) {
                    setState(() {
                      _countryName.add(guess);
                      countries_info[guess]!["color"] = "Colors.green";
```

Second page :
Here I want to change the color of the text depending on the value I changed in the first file

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: continentCountry.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 3,
              mainAxisSpacing: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 5),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 3, color: splashBackground),
                color: purpleList,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 10,
              child: Text(continentCountry[index], style: setColors()),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

setColors() {
  for (final value in countries_info.values) {
    print(value["color"]);
    if (value["color"] == "Colors.green") {
      return TextStyle(color: Colors.green);
    } else {
      return TextStyle(color: Colors.red);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about, and pick one of all state management approaches.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: I'm using setState and I don't get why it doesn't work.. That's why I'm asking for help.. Read the docs already..

Comment: "setState" is widget specific, so to manage a shared state between routes you need something else. You could e.g. go for flutter_bloc or riverpod or similar.

Comment: I use the setState tu change the value of a key in my map, can I use a Provider to do so? I don't see how..

Comment: If Provider is your choice, then you can expose the object using the Provider widget, then watch and adjust the object via the BuildContext. A small clarification, you can manage the state via "setState" as well by passing the value and a callback to e.g. child widgets as well. But that will quickly spiral out of control.

Comment: I'm still new to this an I'm not sur I understand what you mean.. Do you have an example I can look into?

Comment: It's all in the link in my answer. Strictly opinionated, but I suggest that you go for either Riverpod or Bloc Library (flutter_bloc). There are other options on the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is when you push to second page there you need to pass your list as arguments and just do on second page with whatever operation you can do because you will get updated list there. As beginner level you can use setState but if your app have large scale then you need to move any State management. But at this time you see that how you can pass arguments from one page to another and pass your list.